# Pass generic list in console app from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, console-application

I have a solution that i need to call a console app from asp.net and need to pass variables. one variable is a generic list of a certain class.

I have tried passing it but I got error that i cannot convert a generic list to a string which is correct.

I am not sure if there is another way to pass this.

I know webservice can solve this issue. But it there any other options?

Is this possible to do or only string are possible to pass

```
Here is the generic list sample.

List<person> personList = new List<person>();
person p = new person();
p.name = "test";
p.age = 12;
p.birthdate = 01/01/2014

personList.add(p)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's in your generic list? Show some code samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Console application accepts only strings. This is defined in the `Main` method as

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

Since you have a complex object list it'll be bit hard to pass this information to the console application (but not impossible). There are several options for you.

1. Pass your values as comma separated values as a string as long as this string is not too long.
2. `Web Services` or a `Web API` as you suggested.
3. `Serialize` your object to an XML file and then `deserialize` in your console application.
4. Write and read from a persistent data store

**UPDATE**

***Sample Code for Option 3 (Write to an XML file)***

I wrote this sample code out of curiosity. Hope this helps to solve your issue.

**ASP.Net Website**

I have a button in my web page (`Default.aspx`) and in it's click event it writes the Person collection/ List  to an XML file. Here's the code behind.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WriteToConsole
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnWriteToConsole_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PersonCollection personList = new PersonCollection();
            // Person 1
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Name = "test 1";
            p.Age = 12;
            p.BirthDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2014");
            personList.Add(p);

            // Person 2
            Person p2 = new Person();
            p2.Name = "test 2";
            p2.Age = 25;
            p2.BirthDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2014");
            personList.Add(p2);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(personList.GetType());

            StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"D:\temp\PersonCollection.xml");
            serializer.Serialize(file, personList);
            file.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And, the `Person.cs` looks like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WriteToConsole
{
    [Serializable]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("PersonCollection")]
    public class PersonCollection : List<Person> {
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {
            this.Name = string.Empty;
            this.Age = 0;
            this.BirthDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
}
```

**Console Application**

Then read the XML file in your console application and display the data in `personList` on the console.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ReadInConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonCollection));
            TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(@"D:\temp\PersonCollection.xml");

            PersonCollection personList = new PersonCollection();
            personList = (PersonCollection)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);            
            textReader.Close();

            if (personList != null && personList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Person p in personList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Person name: {0}, Age: {1} and DOB: {2}", p.Name, p.Age, p.BirthDate.ToShortDateString());
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your console application you should have the same Person class as a modal (This is same as the Person class in your Web Application. Only the namespace is different).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ReadInConsole
{
    [Serializable]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("PersonCollection")]
    public class PersonCollection : List<Person>
    {
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {
            this.Name = string.Empty;
            this.Age = 0;
            this.BirthDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you understand the code.

Comment: I have tried pass as xml. But the elements are being tagged as a different args.

Lets say I pass a person xml.<person><name>test</name><person>
<person is args(0) <name> is args[1] and so on

Comment: Can you show me how you did it? Then I might be able to solve the issue

Comment: XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("PersonInfo", new XElement("Persons", personlist.Select(x => new XElement("Person", new XAttribute("Name", x.Name))))));

Comment: Hi Sam Thanks for this. I will try now on my solution

Comment: It'll be a different solution if you are trying to share the same memory (keeping XML in memory) between two application contexts.

Comment: No you didn't :D You just accepted the answer. I get more points when you do both :P Happy to give a helping hand to someone.

Comment: Also read about Memory Mapped Files this helps to share a file in virtual memory between two processes. Here's a link to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thumbs up for both now.